# mysql in xampp for php

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am trying to start mysql on xammp control panel, but I am getting this error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofzbm.png)

I want to connect phpMyAdmin through xampp. I have tried to uninstall and reinstall xampp several times, but I am still getting the same error. I also copied the xampp path to the environment variable

Comment: As the error suggests the port `3306` is already in use. You could run: `netstat -b -p TCP` and look for port 3306

Answer (score 0):

the port 3306 is already in use with ather software
whith text editor open file (my.ini)
in (xampp\mysql\bin)  directory and edit    `port=3306`
to ather port not used for example port=3333
in line 20 and 29 save and start